# How do I sort a vector with names containing many strings of numbers in R?

Tags: r, string, data-analysis

I have a list of names which I would like to sort by the R value in ascending order.

`[1] "W2345_S-001-R2-20D.datavalue.csv"     "W2346_S-001-R4-20D.datavalue.csv"`

`[3] "W2347_S-001-R1-20D.datavalue.csv"     "W2348_S-001-R3-20D.datavalue.csv"`

`[5] "W2349_S-001-R5-20D.datavalue.csv"`

However, `mixedsort` only gives the above (sorting by W values) but I would like to arrange them by R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, ignoring the other numbers contained in the names.
Hence the output should be

`[1] "W2347_S-001-R1-20D.datavalue.csv"  "W2345_S-001-R2-20D.datavalue.csv"`

`[3] "W2348_S-001-R3-20D.datavalue.csv"  "W2346_S-001-R4-20D.datavalue.csv"`

`[5] "W2349_S-001-R5-20D.datavalue.csv"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list_of_names <- c("W2345_S-001-R2-20D_790.datavalue.csv",
                   "W2346_S-001-R4-20D_792.datavalue.csv",
                   "W2347_S-001-R1-20D_789.datavalue.csv",
                   "W2348_S-001-R3-20D_791.datavalue.csv",
                   "W2349_S-001-R5-20D_793.datavalue.csv")

library(stringr)

names_order <- order(as.numeric(str_match(list_of_names, "-R\\s*(.*?)\\s*-")[,2]))

list_of_names[names_order]

[1] "W2347_S-001-R1-20D_789.datavalue.csv" "W2345_S-001-R2-20D_790.datavalue.csv"
[3] "W2348_S-001-R3-20D_791.datavalue.csv" "W2346_S-001-R4-20D_792.datavalue.csv"
[5] "W2349_S-001-R5-20D_793.datavalue.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
# Your data
vals<-c( "W2345_S-001-R2-20D_790.datavalue.csv",
         "W2346_S-001-R4-20D_792.datavalue.csv",
         "W2347_S-001-R1-20D_789.datavalue.csv",
         "W2348_S-001-R3-20D_791.datavalue.csv",
         "W2349_S-001-R5-20D_793.datavalue.csv")

library(stringr)

vals_df<-data.frame(vals,
           position=str_extract(vals,"(?<=R)\\d{1}")|>
                 as.numeric())

vals_df[order(vals_df$position),]$vals

[1] "W2347_S-001-R1-20D_789.datavalue.csv" "W2345_S-001-R2-20D_790.datavalue.csv"
[3] "W2348_S-001-R3-20D_791.datavalue.csv" "W2346_S-001-R4-20D_792.datavalue.csv"
[5] "W2349_S-001-R5-20D_793.datavalue.csv
```